# nginx url rewrite

Tags: regex, nginx

How to [nginx rewrite](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite) within `location` context the following:

`/` => `/myurl/`

`/abc/` => `/myurl/abc/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the following will do the trick:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^ /myurl/$uri; 
}
```

Note that the /abc/ wil match the / prefix (and be rewritten to /myurl/abc/), so it doesn't need a sepperate rewrite

Also note that you need to add an additional "location /myurl/ {...}" block to avoid getting incoming request to that url to get rewritten to /myurl/myurl/... and so on

Comment: cobaco can you elaborate on the second part to prevent unnecessary addons? I think I am running into issues because of that and I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: basically: if you go to /myurl/ then at that point $uri = /myurl/. That gets rewriten to /myurl/myurl/ at which point the rewriten url matches the rewrite rule again with $uri=/myurl/myurl/ and so on. By adding a specific `location /myurl/ {}` block you avoid that, because that's a more specific match that matches anything that already has the /myurl/ attached in front, and being more specific it gets precedence

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this does the trick:

```
rewrite ^(/.*)$  ^/admin/$1 break;
```

Any other suggestion?